# Laravel Form Request Dynamic Fields dissapear on Redirect

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, validation, field

I have a form, a button to add one more item to form, and Form Request validation file.
All works fine except one thing:
When user adds one more field (after hitting "+Add doc number") and enters value which is already in the DB:

[image]

Validation works fine and redirects user to the same page, but now only one field is present:

[image]

QUESTION: how to make the all fields present in pic 1 remain in pic 2?

My code:

Form itself:

```
<form>
  <div class='inputs'>    
    <label>Doc number: </label>
    <input type="text" name="doc_fullnumber[1]" value="{{old('doc_fullnumber.1')}}">
  </div>
  <button id='add_item'>Add doc number</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

a jquery code which adds one more input if user clicks the "button":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_item').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var i = 2;
        $new_docnumber = $(         
            '<br><br>'+
            '<label>Номер док-та: </label>'+ 
            '<input type="text" name="doc_fullnumber['+i+']" placeholder="Номер док-та" value="{{old('doc_fullnumber.[i]')}}">');
        $('.inputs').append($new_passenger);
    })
})
```

a working form validation in a Laravel's FormRequest file:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'doc_fullnumber' => 'unique:tourists'

    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return ['doc_fullnumber.unique' => 'Doc number is already in DB!'];
}
```

Appreciate any help folks!

Answer (score 1):

This is normal since original DOM loaded without elements appended by JS, I suggest that you use JQuery(Ajax) instead.

if you still want to use your code, you should use JS to recreate the request parameters, you will need to loop through parameters of the URL request by using key array to create inputs name="key" value="value", I hope that help.

This is the code to get prams:

```
var qd = {};
if (location.search) 
  location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
  var s = item.split("="),
    k = s[0],
    v = s[1] && decodeURIComponent(s[1]);
  (qd[k] = qd[k] || []).push(v)
})
```

Comment: Or he can make an ajax and if it's successful then submit the form and if it's not then return errors and the new added inputs will stay

Comment: @lewis4u thank you, I edit my answer to clarify using JQuery Ajax

Answer (score 1):

try this one

return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());

Comment: where exactly should I add it? I am using Form Validation, not just regular validation.

Comment: under your validation , if all validation passed then return  ```Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());```